# Extracting alphanumeric values

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I've got files in the following format

```
 m.dat -c16 -S32m  1.3768702014349401 s, rate:  3.2434134115834929 GB/s.
 m.dat -c16 -S64m  1.0852226612623781 s, rate:  4.115062684139847 GB/s.
 m.dat -c20 -S1m  3.8889309875667095 s, rate:  1.1483256688332133 GB/s.
 m.dat -c20 -S2m  16.622251618420705 s, rate:  0.26866151348562284 GB/s.
 m.dat -c20 -S4m  4.5505061785224825 s, rate:  0.98137637927430543 GB/s.
 m.dat -c20 -S8m  2.4563963813707232 s, rate:  1.8180124800752873 GB/s.
```

and I would like to extract different **numeric** values from them. In particular, I am after getting something similar to this:

```
m.dat 20 4  4.5505061785224825  0.98137637927430543
```

That is, I would like to extract the **numeric** values **without** characters **plus** the first field of every row in the file.

I can easily get the different field of every row with `awk`, but those values would also include `-c` and `-S`, which are not of interest.

```
awk '{print $1, $2, $3, $4}' file
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a tricky bit of perl:

```
$ perl -lane '@fields=(@F[0], /(\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\d*\.\d+)/g); print "@fields"' file
m.dat 16 32 1.3768702014349401 3.2434134115834929
m.dat 16 64 1.0852226612623781 4.115062684139847
m.dat 20 1 3.8889309875667095 1.1483256688332133
m.dat 20 2 16.622251618420705 0.26866151348562284
m.dat 20 4 4.5505061785224825 0.98137637927430543
m.dat 20 8 2.4563963813707232 1.8180124800752873
```

Gotta run, explanation upon request.

Comment: pipe output into `column -t` to make it pretty

Comment: Allow me to explain: `-a` splits each input line into an array of fields by whitespace, which gives access to the 1st field as `@F[0]`. You then combine that 1st field with the array of numeric tokens on the line, obtained with a regex, to form output array `@fields`. By passing `@fields` inside double quotes to `print`, the array elements are converted to a string with a single space between elements.  Regex `/…/g` is implicitly applied to the input line as a whole, and returns all (`g`) matches as an array. At least with the sample input, the simpler `/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/g` would work too.

Comment: thanks @mklement0. The more complicated regex captures fractional numbers with no integer part. If those don't appear in the input, simplify.

Answer (score 2):

another `perl` solution

```
$ perl -lne 'print join "\t", /^\s*\K\S+|\d+\.\d+|\d+/g' file 
m.dat   16  32  1.3768702014349401  3.2434134115834929
m.dat   16  64  1.0852226612623781  4.115062684139847
m.dat   20  1   3.8889309875667095  1.1483256688332133
m.dat   20  2   16.622251618420705  0.26866151348562284
m.dat   20  4   4.5505061785224825  0.98137637927430543
m.dat   20  8   2.4563963813707232  1.8180124800752873
```

- `join "\t"` use tab as output delimiter, change it to any other string sequence if needed
- `/^\s*\K\S+|\d+\.\d+|\d+/g` regex defining text to extract

  - `^\s*\K\S+` from beginning of line, excluding optional space, get non-space characters - gets us row label `m.dat` in this case
  - `\d+\.\d+` extract fractional numbers with at least one digit before/after the `.`
  - `\d+` order is important, extract fractional first and then get non-fractional sequence of digits

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{print $1,substr($2,3),substr(substr($3,3),1,length(substr($3,3))-1),$4,$7}' file
```

Output:

```
m.dat 16 32 1.3768702014349401 3.2434134115834929
m.dat 16 64 1.0852226612623781 4.115062684139847
m.dat 20 1 3.8889309875667095 1.1483256688332133
m.dat 20 2 16.622251618420705 0.26866151348562284
m.dat 20 4 4.5505061785224825 0.98137637927430543
m.dat 20 8 2.4563963813707232 1.8180124800752873
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a pragmatic combination of `paste`, `cut`, `awk`, and `tr`:

```
$ paste -d' ' <(cut -d' ' -f1 file) <(awk '{print $2, $3, $4, $7}' file | tr -dC '0-9. \n')

m.dat 16 32 1.3768702014349401 3.2434134115834929
m.dat 16 64 1.0852226612623781 4.115062684139847
m.dat 20 1 3.8889309875667095 1.1483256688332133
m.dat 20 2 16.622251618420705 0.26866151348562284
m.dat 20 4 4.5505061785224825 0.98137637927430543
m.dat 20 8 2.4563963813707232 1.8180124800752873
```

This is not the fastest approach, but it's easy to understand:

- `cut -d' ' -f1 file` outputs the 1st space-separated field from file `file`.
- `awk '{print $2, $3, $4, $7 }'` outputs `file`'s whitespace-separated fields 2, 3, 4, and 7, separated with a single space on output.

  - `tr -dC '0-9 \n'` removes (`-d`) all characters except (`-C`) digits, spaces, and newlines from `awk`'s output.
- `paste -d' ' <(...) <(...)` merges the corresponding lines from the output of the `cut` command and the `awk` pipeline, separated by a single space, using two [process substitutions](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution).

Answer (score 1):

User-defined `awk` functions aren't used that often, but in this case they allow a simple, extensible solution:

```
$ awk '
function strip(val) { gsub("[^0-9.]", "", val); return val } # keep only digits and "."
{ print $1, strip($2), strip($3), $4, $7 }
' file

m.dat 16 32 1.3768702014349401 3.2434134115834929
m.dat 16 64 1.0852226612623781 4.115062684139847
m.dat 20 1 3.8889309875667095 1.1483256688332133
m.dat 20 2 16.622251618420705 0.26866151348562284
m.dat 20 4 4.5505061785224825 0.98137637927430543
m.dat 20 8 2.4563963813707232 1.8180124800752873
```

---

Alternatively, *GNU* `awk`'s `gensub()` function allows for a relatively concise solution:

```
awk '{ print $1, gensub("[^0-9]+", "", "g", $2), gensub("[^0-9]+", "", "g", $3), $4, $7 }'
```

Answer (score 1):

I want the award for simplest idea and least code.  If all you want is numeric data, use non-numerics as your separator:

```
$ awk -F '[^0-9.-]+' '{split($0, a, / +/); print a[2], $4, $6, $7, $8}' dat
m.dat 16 32 1.3768702014349401 3.2434134115834929
m.dat 16 64 1.0852226612623781 4.115062684139847
m.dat 20 1 3.8889309875667095 1.1483256688332133
m.dat 20 2 16.622251618420705 0.26866151348562284
m.dat 20 4 4.5505061785224825 0.98137637927430543
m.dat 20 8 2.4563963813707232 1.8180124800752873
```

To tack on the first field, split the record two ways.

Comment: @_James K. Lowden and if I want the first field too?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest striping all the non numeric values (still needs improvements to handle the `.`):

```
$ awk '{ for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) { gsub("[^0-9.]*","",$i); } gsub("\\s+", " "); $NF=""; print ; }' data.dat 
m.dat 16 32 1.3768702014349401 3.2434134115834929 
m.dat 16 64 1.0852226612623781 4.115062684139847 
m.dat 20 1 3.8889309875667095 1.1483256688332133 
m.dat 20 2 16.622251618420705 0.26866151348562284 
m.dat 20 4 4.5505061785224825 0.98137637927430543 
m.dat 20 8 2.4563963813707232 1.8180124800752873
```

**Edit:** I figured the additional point I had (when including the `.` in the regexp) was due to the first field being replaced as well. I've modified the answer accordingly.

Comment: Good idea stripping out the non-numerics, but you only need to do it for columns 2 and 3 (which avoids the `.` problem). And you can simplify the printing as well: `awk '{for (i=2;i<=3;i++) gsub("[^0-9]","",$i); print $1,$2,$3,$4,$7}'`

Comment: @jas: solved the issue! I didn't understand why I got an additional `.` when my regexp was `[^0-9.]`; now I have!